How to print out location in Polars?
I'm making a program which detects any negative values included within an excel spreadsheet.
I've converted my dataframe to Polars for faster operation.
I've managed to printout the columns but not the rows.
How do I go about doing this?
book = r"filename.xlsx"

pd_df = pd.read_excel(book, sheet_name='sheet_name')
df = pl.from_pandas(pd_df)

negative_values = False
for col in df.columns:
    if df[col].dtype == pl.datatypes.Float64 or df[col].dtype == pl.datatypes.Int64:
        filtered_df = df.filter(pl.col(col)<0)
        if filtered_df.height > 0:
            negative_values = True
            print(col)

if not negative_values:
    print("No negative values found in the DataFrame.")


You should include some dummy data in order to make your example runnable, e.g.
pl.DataFrame({
   "A": ["a", "b", "c", "d"],
   "B": [-1, 2, -3, -4],
   "C": [-0.1, 2, 3, 4.0]
}).write_excel("filename.xlsx")

df = pl.read_excel("filename.xlsx")

You can test all the columns at once:
df.select(pl.col(pl.Int64, pl.Float64) < 0)

shape: (4, 2)
┌───────┬───────┐
│ B     ┆ C     │
│ ---   ┆ ---   │
│ bool  ┆ bool  │
╞═══════╪═══════╡
│ true  ┆ true  │
│ false ┆ false │
│ true  ┆ false │
│ true  ┆ true  │
└───────┴───────┘


(see also cs.numeric())

You could then replace the true values with the "row number".
(df.select(pl.col(pl.Int64, pl.Float64) < 0)
   .with_columns(
      pl.when(pl.all())
        .then(pl.int_range(pl.len()))
        .name.keep()
   )
)

shape: (4, 2)
┌──────┬──────┐
│ B    ┆ C    │
│ ---  ┆ ---  │
│ i64  ┆ i64  │
╞══════╪══════╡
│ 0    ┆ 0    │
│ null ┆ null │
│ 2    ┆ null │
│ 3    ┆ 3    │
└──────┴──────┘

Alternatively, you could add a row number, .unpivot() and .filter() the true rows.
(df.select(pl.col(pl.Int64, pl.Float64) < 0)
   .with_row_index()
   .unpivot(index = "index")
   .filter("value")
   .drop("value")
)

shape: (5, 2)
┌───────┬──────────┐
│ index ┆ variable │
│ ---   ┆ ---      │
│ u32   ┆ str      │
╞═══════╪══════════╡
│ 0     ┆ B        │
│ 2     ┆ B        │
│ 3     ┆ B        │
│ 0     ┆ C        │
│ 3     ┆ C        │
└───────┴──────────┘


.arg_true has this warning in its docs: Modifies number of rows returned, so will fail in combination with other expressions. Use as only expression in select / with_columns. Appending -4 to both B and C causes the above to fail with polars.exceptions.ComputeError: Series length 2 doesn't match the DataFrame height of 3

Thanks @levantpied - I completely missed that gotcha.

You can use df.with_row_index, then filter, then select the index column:
import polars as pl

df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "foo": [1, 2, -5, -6, 0],
        "bar": [-1, -2, 5, 6, 0],
    }
)

for column in df.columns:
    if df[column].dtype == pl.Int64:
        negative_indexes = df.with_row_index().filter(pl.col(column) < 0)["index"]
        if not negative_indexes.is_empty():
            print(
                f"column {column} has negative values at indexes: {negative_indexes.to_list()}"
            )

Output:
column foo has negative values at indexes: [2, 3]
column bar has negative values at indexes: [0, 1]

